# Cannot kill file from VBA macro when another instance of Word is open

Tags: vba, ms-word, kill

This code is in a word macro template in the word start up menu. It can be executed from any word document.

```
Dim myFile As String
Dim myPath As String
myPath = ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
myFile = Dir$(myPath & "*Invoice.pdf")

If Len(myFile) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print Len(myFile)
    Debug.Print myFile
    Kill myFile
End If
```

When I run this code I get an error message "File not found" if I have  another MS Word file open when I opened this instance of a word document and executed the macro.

Length is > 0
Filename (Greenbriar - Invoice.pdf) is correct and present. (there is always only one pdf with "Invoice" in the filename in any given folder)

I do not get this error message if no other word document is open.

How can I modify the code to run even if another Word document is open?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something to do with the `ActiveDocument` call I assume...

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveDocument.Path` refers to the directory of the other document when it is open. `ThisDocument.Path` should refer to the directory that contains the template that contains the code. See [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-35260.html) for a nice discussion.